# rabbitmq doesn't work, gives transport error, how to solve it?

Tags: node.js, docker, rabbitmq, nestjs

Well, everything was going normally until when I did docker-compose up or up --build, it gave an error that I will show after my codes below.

my rabbit configuration 1:

```
export class rmqModule {
  static registrarRmq(service: string, queue: string): DynamicModule {
    const providers = [
      {
        provide: service,
        useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => {
          const USER = configService.get('RABBITMQ_USER');
          const PASSWORD = configService.get('RABBITMQ_PASS');
          const HOST = configService.get('RABBITMQ_HOST');
          return ClientProxyFactory.create({
            transport: Transport.RMQ,
            options: {
              urls: [`amqp://${USER}:${PASSWORD}@${HOST}`],
              queue,
              queueOptions: {
                durable: true, 
              },
            },
          });
        },
        inject: [ConfigService],
      },
    ];

    return {
      module: rmqModule,
      providers,
      exports: providers,
    };
  }
}
```

my configuration 2:

```
@Injectable()
export class LibService {
    constructor(
        private readonly configService: ConfigService
    ){}

    moduloRmq(queue: string): RmqOptions {
        const usuario = this.configService.get('RABBITMQ_USER')
        const senha = this.configService.get('RABBITMQ_PASS');
        const porta = this.configService.get('RABBITMQ_HOST');

        return {
            transport: Transport.RMQ,
            options: {
                urls: [`amqp://${usuario}:${senha}@${porta}`],
                noAck: false,
                queue,
                queueOptions: {
                    durable: true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

my .env rabbit:

```
RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=Naox
RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=root
RABBITMQ_USER=Norm
RABBITMQ_PASS=root
RABBITMQ_HOST=root2
```

my app.module:

```
@Module({
  imports: [rmqModule.registrarRmq('AUTH_SERVICE', process.env.RABBITMQ_AUTH_QUEUE)],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [],
})
```

my controler client proxy:

```
@Controller()
export class AppController {
  constructor(@Inject('AUTH_SERVICE') private readonly authServico: ClientProxy) {}
```

I think these are the codes I need to show, if you need anything else, you can tell me.

So, back to the error, when I try to upload my container, which seems to be OK, I get an error, telling me these two logs.

```
 ERROR [Server] Connection to transport failed. Trying to reconnect...
```

```
 ERROR [Server] Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN root2
```

What should I do here? nothing I tried helped me

Comment: What is the host `root2`? What is that suppose to point to?

Comment: hi jay,The HOST specifies the AMQP server to which the connection will be established. It indicates the address of the AMQP server to which I am trying to connect.

Comment: I was stupid, I decided to change it to rabbitmq:5672, and worked